# smart pointer to const in function's signature

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, const-correctness

I was wondering if the implicit cast I have when passing a shared_ptr < T> as argument to a function taking shared_ptr < const T> involves some hidden costs (such as the construction of an extra copy).

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<const Widget> ){}

int main(){
   std::shared_ptr<Widget> p; 
   f(p);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that in both cases I am paying for the refcount increment and decrement.

Moreover I wonder why the code doesn't compile if I define the function `f()` with the following signature:

```
void f(shared_ptr<const Widget>& ){}
```

What wonders me more is the fact that this does:

```
void f(const shared_ptr<const Widget>& ){}
```

Comment: Thx, I edited the question.

Comment: 1. What is `T`? 2. Provide a compilable example or at least an error message.

Comment: If `f` only cares about using the `Widget` for it's duration, pass a `const Widget *` (or `const Widget &` if you know it is non-null). Only if `f` wishes to participate in owning the `Widget` (i.e. it will store the pointer somewhere) should you pass a `shared_ptr`

Comment: @Caleth let's assume that I cannot change the signature of f. Anyway, I totally agree with your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why does pass by value work?**

Your code works because of the [`smart_ptr` constructor overload (9)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;
```

> Constructs a shared_ptr which shares ownership of the object managed
>   by r. If r manages no object, *this manages no object too. The
>   template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is
>   not implicitly convertible to (until C++17)compatible with (since
>   C++17) T*.

**Why does it not compile when the method expects a `shared_ptr<const Widget>&`?**

If you change the signature to

```
void f(shared_ptr<const Widget>& ){}
```

You cannot have the conversion and passing to the method in one step anymore, because a temporary (the one resulting from the conversion) cannot bind to a non-const reference. However, you can still do it in two steps:

```
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> p; 
    std::shared_ptr<const Widget> p2{p};
    // f(p);  // error: cannot bind non-const reference to temporary
    f(p2);    // OK
    return 0;
}
```

**Is there some overhead?**

Concerning overhead: Yes there is a `smart_ptr<const Widget>` being contructed and then passed to the method (like it is shown explicitly in the above snippet).

**Why does it again work when the method expects a `const shared_ptr<const Widget>&`?**

Concerning your edit, why does it work again if you change the signature to this:

```
void f(const shared_ptr<const Widget>& ){}
```

In that case if you pass a `shared_ptr<Widget>`, there is still a converison taking place. However, now the temporary resulting from the conversion is allowed to bind to a const reference. Anyhow the method is not allowed to modify it, so there is no danger in allowing to pass a temporary.

**Just another example**

Note that temporaries not binding to non-const references is a rare case of C++ helping you to avoid stupid mistakes. Consider this:

```
void foo(int& x) { x += 2; }
int bar() { return 3; }

int main() { foo(bar()); }   // error !
```

It just doesnt make much sense to pass a r-value to a function that expects a non-const l-value reference. You'd have no way to observe the changes made by `foo` on the value returned by `bar`.

**Passing smartpointers @ cpp core guidelines**

Concerning passing smartpointers to funcions, note that the [cpp coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-resource) has some items on that. The bottomline is: If the method is not participating in reference counting (probably the most common case) then dont pass a smartpointer but a raw pointer.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that passing a smart pointer to a function is considered a smell unless that function is taking ownership of the pointer. The idea is you should only be passing a live (and raw) pointer to methods that just need to use the object.

Comment: @Mgetz yes it is worth mentioning ;-) Thanks for doing it.

Comment: Hi user463035818, I edited my question with another case. I could write it in a separate question but I think that it's better to keep the stuff together since they are intimately related. I hope you or some benevolent have time to edit your answer discussing the "const & const" case. Thanks

Comment: @jimifiki well sorry, ignore my comment (deleted). I was too fast in writing it ;). My answer actually already explains why what you added does work. Will edit the question to explain a bit more...